# How to lock tkinter button after pressing on it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

how to lock the button after pressing on it, until the other button is pressed or  until I closed the program interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by locking the button, I think you mean disabling. Disabling is just you not being able to click the button until you define the state back to 'normal'

Here is some sample code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def doDisable():
    b2.configure(state=DISABLED)

root = Tk()
b2 = Button(root, text="Disable button", command=doDisable)
b2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But is this `atomic` ? What if  a second button click occurs, before the call to b2.configure has finished?